# achieving polymorphism within the parent class by using instanceof to set attribute

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I have a parent class called AggDef which is the base type of some child classes (TermAggDef, StatAggDeff etc.). The class is defined below.

I have some code in another class that loops over a list of AggDef objects and get's their types. 
protected Map aggregations = new HashMap();

```
public List<String> getAggregationTypes(){
    HashSet<String> aggTypes = new HashSet<String>();
      Iterator it = aggregations.entrySet().iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         AggDef aggDef = (AggDef) pair.getValue();
         aggTypes.add(aggDef.getType());
      }
      List<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
      retList.addAll(aggTypes);
    return retList;
}
```

My Question is, **could I achieve this polymorphic assignment of the type attribute in the parent class itself? Because wherever an AggDef object would be used, it would know what specific type it is. My team member said I should implement the setType method in the actual child classes.** But I don't think what I have here is wrong. Any help or elaboration on the accuracy of my approach would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
public abstract class AggDef implements Cloneable {
    protected String name;
    protected String term;
    protected String type;
    ...

    protected List<AggDef> subAggregations;

    public void setType(AggDef def){
        if(def instanceof TermAggDef){
            def.type = "terms";
        } 
        else if (def instanceof StatAggDef){
            def.type = "terms_stats";
        }
        else if (def instanceof RangeAggDef){
            def.type = "range";
        }
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    protected AggDef() {
        setType(this);
    }

    protected AggDef(String term) {
        this.term = term;
        setType(this);
    }

    protected AggDef(String name, String term) {
        this.name = name;
        this.term = term;
        setType(this);
    }


    public AggDef(String term, String order, int size, int offset, boolean isAllTerms) {
        this.term = term;
        this.size = size;
        ...

        setType(this);
    }


    public AggDef(String name, String term, String order, int size, int offset, boolean isAllTerms) {
        this.name = name;
        this.term = term;
       ...
        setType(this);
    }
 }
```

Comment: why do you need setType method, and why is it getting the class as an argument (and not just work on 'this')? in any case, a better way to do it would be to make it abstract method, and each implementing class should define it's own type

Comment: Thank you. But my question was, is this accurate the way I have it? Or this will not work?

Comment: will it work? yes. Is it accurate? not at all. the whole idea in abstract classes is that you are letting the sub classes have their own specific implementation of the method. what you did in your setType function is have a specific implementation per sub-class, but instead of having it in the sub-class, you have it all in the upper one. so it will work, but this is bad object oriented programming

Comment: Not according to one of the answer below. I need a concrete answer. Some people are saying yes this will work. Others are saying no this won't. Any reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*AggDef* only knows about itself and can never know anything about it's children.  So when it calls `setType(AggDef)` the JVM will reference the locally defined method and not the over-riden.

Hopefully, to help further nail the subject in let's say you have:

```
AggDef aDefObj = new AggDef();
TermAggDef taDefObj = new TermAggDef();
```

then that means the following:

```
aDefObj instanceOf AggDef // true 
aDefObj instanceOf TermAggDef  // false 
taDefObj instanceOf AggDef // true
taDefObj instanceOf TermAggDef // true
```

Check out Oracle's [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) doc specifically Casting.

Comment: According to @Nir in the comments, this should work fine.